# Getting data from two tables with join and performing Count and GroupBy

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to fetch data from two tables `SaleInvoices` and `Customers`. Both are linked with a Foreign Key `CustomerId`. I am trying to get Customers repeated record count and grouping them. But it generates the Following error.

```
USE iBusinessFlex;
SELECT SaleInvoices.InvoiceID,
       SaleInvoices.CustomerID,
       Customers.ContactName,
       Customers.CNIC,
       Customers.City,
       Customers.CellNumber,
       Customers.CompanyName,
       COUNT(*)
FROM SaleInvoices
     INNER JOIN Customers ON SaleInvoices.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerId
WHERE SaleInvoices.UpdatedDate >= '2017-01-02 16:53:53.253'
  AND SaleInvoices.UpdatedDate <= '2019-01-02 16:53:53.253'
GROUP BY Customers.ContactName;
```

**Error i am getting is**

> Column 'SaleInvoices.InvoiceID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Comment: well, the error message says it all. you are just grouping by Customers.ContactName, but you don't use any aggregate function on the columns selected. Either you group by all columns in your select, or you have to remove them from the select. depends what you're going to approach

Comment: Whitespace and line breaks are *really* important to writing readable and maintainable SQL. I recommend taking the time to format your queries with both so that others, and yourself, and easily read your queries. you'll also find things much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: In regards to your question, what are trying to achieve here? I suspect adding every column to the `GROUP BY` won't give you the result you are after.

Comment: @Larnu got it ill keep in mind next time thanks sir :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version with grouping by all columns in the SELECT:

```
Select SaleInvoices.InvoiceID
      ,SaleInvoices.CustomerID
      ,Customers.ContactName
      ,Customers.CNIC
      ,Customers.City
      ,Customers.CellNumber
      ,Customers.CompanyName
      ,Count(*)
 From SaleInvoices 
 INNER JOIN Customers 
 ON SaleInvoices.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerId 
 Where SaleInvoices.UpdatedDate >= '2017-01-02 16:53:53.253' 
 AND SaleInvoices.UpdatedDate<= '2019-01-02 16:53:53.253' 
 GROUP BY SaleInvoices.InvoiceID
      ,SaleInvoices.CustomerID
      ,Customers.ContactName
      ,Customers.CNIC
      ,Customers.City
      ,Customers.CellNumber
      ,Customers.CompanyName
```

Version with removing the columns from the select, without changing the group by:

```
Select Customers.ContactName
      ,Count(*)
 From SaleInvoices 
 INNER JOIN Customers 
 ON SaleInvoices.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerId 
 Where SaleInvoices.UpdatedDate >= '2017-01-02 16:53:53.253' 
 AND SaleInvoices.UpdatedDate<= '2019-01-02 16:53:53.253' 
 GROUP BY Customers.ContactName
```

Another way would be to use aggregate functions like MIN(), MAX(),... on all columns of the selection:

```
Select MIN(SaleInvoices.InvoiceID)
      ,MIN(SaleInvoices.CustomerID)
      ,Customers.ContactName
      ,MIN(Customers.CNIC)
      ,MIN(Customers.City)
      ,MIN(Customers.CellNumber)
      ,MIN(Customers.CompanyName)
      ,Count(*)
 From SaleInvoices 
 INNER JOIN Customers 
 ON SaleInvoices.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerId 
 Where SaleInvoices.UpdatedDate >= '2017-01-02 16:53:53.253' 
 AND SaleInvoices.UpdatedDate<= '2019-01-02 16:53:53.253' 
 GROUP BY Customers.ContactName
```

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping the output of the result set by `Customers.ContactName`, therefore, you are only allowed to have `Customers.ContactName` in the `select`.
You have two options:

1) Either aggregate all the columns that you have put in the `select`.
2) Or have all of them participated in the `group by` clause.